# && exit does not quit as expected, takes it as text string in cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, wget

So im trying to run multiple commands in a one command line, im using WGET to download a few files to a local path this part works so far.

Here is what Ive got

> startInfo.Arguments = @"/K wget -x -np -S -N -nH -r -R ""index.html*""
>   http://my-server.ip -P """ +
>   Properties.Settings.Default.userAddonDir+" && exit";

with this I should expect CMD to launch WGET with the command line:

> -x -np -S -N -nH -r -R ""index.html*""

from my server:

> http://my-server.ip

to my users local path for example:

> E:/Folder/Sub Folder/

then once wget is finished it should see

> && Exit

and close cmd...

things to note, the users local path is likely to have white space so I've wrapped it in quotes to prevent the path being cut off. (hence all the quotes)

but what the path resolves to is odd. not to sure

> E:/Folder/Sub Folder/ && exit/

If I place any more "" it breaks any ideas or pointers as im at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing && exit? Just pass /c instead of /k and cams will exit when it’s done.

Comment: @Cromz I agree with Chad Nedzlek. Do not start `cmd.exe` with parameter `/K` to __keep__ the command process running after executing the command, but with `/C` to __close__ after running the command and `&& exit` is not necessary at all. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` for help on Windows command processor and its options.

Comment: But why does your C# application run `cmd.exe` which runs a third-party tool without file extension and file path not available by default on Windows to download one or more files from a server using HTTP? This task can be also coded in C# directly which would make the compiled C# application independent on Windows command processor and the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and third-party tool __wget__.

Comment: the /C did the trick, my issue with using WGET is because it has buit-in timestamp checking to download the latest files over http at the time I started this app (2 years ago, I've recently returned to the project) WGET seemed to be the quickest option, if this is not the case then I stand corrected. but thank you for the advise guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your command to

```
string x = @"E:\temp";
string t = @"/K wget -x -np -S -N -nH -r -R ""index.html*"" http://my-server.ip -P """ + 
           x + @""" && exit";
```

After the operator + the initial verbatim character is no more effective. You need to reapply it to the last part of your string constant *&& exit*

However, have you tried to launch your command with /C instead of /K?
This will automatically close the command window so you don't need anymore the Exit command